# Is including passages of books or articles into an answer admissible?

Tags: discussion

In my answer to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/why-is-the-wittig-reaction-syn-stereoselective/5341#5341) question I included a whole passage of a textbook as an image in order to save me the time to write up this part myself. Is this ok (as long as I give a reference to the source, of course) or are there some legal issues?

Comment: Whoa, long answer. Looks like I already upvoted it though :)

Comment: @ManishEarth Originally, I wanted to keep my answer short, but when the OP asked for details concerning the specific way the reactants approach one another, I couldn't think of a way to avoid a long answer ;)

Comment: Note: if the OP asks for more details for an answer that is addressing the question, you're under no obligation to provide them. Of course, if you want to, that's great :) I'm particularly fond of longer answers, because there are a lot more treasures buried in them.

Comment: @ManishEarth In this case I took the opportunity to get my thoughts on the subject straight, though it took a lot more time than I expected. It is mostly an "educated guess" on my side, so I also hope that experienced users who read it and discover flaws in my interpretation can correct me.

Comment: Yep, I find that answering stuff is a great opportunity to un-abstractify thoughts. This is true for teaching in general, for that matter (I'm not a teacher, but I do try explaining stuff to those who ask for it). And, of course, answering leads to people pointing out where one went wrong. Always good to know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is OK. Try to use blockquote formatting (select the text and use the quotation mark button on the editing toolbar) when quoting *text* from a book. In this case you've used an image, so you don't need to blockquote.

Stack Exchange is protected as a DMCA safe harbor, so even if copyright violations are posted, neither Stack Exchange is not liable (you may be, but till date I haven't seen a case where that has happened). If the copyright holder wishes, he can easily submit a DMCA takedown request to SE, and they will remove the relevant content.

---

While it's not against the rules to quote from books, it's always a good idea to have a good amount of "wrapper" material that you've written to go around the quote. This is to better tailor the answer to the question (a quote rarely *exactly* addresses a question), and also to make the answer less dependent on the quote. Even *before* the huge edit, your answer had a nice amount of wrapper text :)

So you're fine. Carry on :)

Comment: [Safe harbor](http://chillingeffects.org/dmca512/faq.cgi#QID125) explicitly mentions the service provider, which is SE in this case.  Is there documentation that supports your argument that the user who answers the question is not liable either?

Comment: @bobthechemist Turns out that it's quote the opposite, a copyright holder can issue a subpeona to get the user's identity. Not really sure what can happen after that.